# End a function only after the end of my interval. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

I have a question regarding a personal project I'm working. I need to create a fade-in and fade-out effect for an object without CSS, and I'm having a hard time with my intervals and function, because I need to finish the fadeout function before moving to the next set of functions.

```
// Interval parameters
var bgtInterval =       [0, false, 50];


// Fade functions will change fill following brightStep array values.

function fadeOut(){ 
  let i = 11;
  OBJECT.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
  bgtInterval[1]=true;
  bgtInterval[0] = setInterval(function(){
    FULLCLOCK.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
    if (i<=0){
      clearInterval(bgtInterval[0]);
      bgtInterval[1]=false;
    }
    i--;
  }, bgtInterval[2]);
}

function fadeIn(){
  let i = 0;
  OBJECT.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
  bgtInterval[1]=true;
  bgtInterval[0] = setInterval(function(){
    FULLCLOCK.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
    if (i>=11){
      clearInterval(bgtInterval[0]);
      bgtInterval[1]=false;
    }
    i++;
  }, bgtInterval[2]);
}
```

-

```
function resetSettings(id){
  fadeOut(); // I need fadeOut to finish before I move forward
  displayReset();
  displayShow();
  fadeIn(); // I need fadeIn to finish before I move out of this function
}

//THE MAIN FUNCTION//
resetSettings();
moreFunctionsHere();
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: Look into callbacks

Comment: change each function to return a Promise that resolves once its function is complete - then use promise chains, or async/await to control your flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Promises and async/await to achieve this very simply

```
var bgtInterval =       [0, false, 50];


// Fade functions will change fill following brightStep array values.

function fadeOut(){ 
  // return the Promise
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let i = 11;
    OBJECT.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
    bgtInterval[1]=true;
    bgtInterval[0] = setInterval(function(){
      FULLCLOCK.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
      if (i<=0){
        clearInterval(bgtInterval[0]);
        bgtInterval[1]=false;
        // resolve when done
        resolve();
      }
      i--;
    }, bgtInterval[2]);
  });
}

function fadeIn(){
  // return a Promise
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let i = 0;
    OBJECT.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
    bgtInterval[1]=true;
    bgtInterval[0] = setInterval(function(){
      FULLCLOCK.setAttribute("fill", brightSteps[i]);
      if (i>=11){
        clearInterval(bgtInterval[0]);
        bgtInterval[1]=false;
        // resolve when done
        resolve();
      }
      i++;
    }, bgtInterval[2]);
  });
}

// use async so we can await a Promise
async function resetSettings(id){
  // wait for fadeOut to finish
  await fadeOut();
  displayReset();
  displayShow();
  await fadeIn();
}

//THE MAIN FUNCTION//
// as we are in global scope, you can't use `async` ... so use Promise.then instead
resetSettings().then(moreFunctionsHere);
```

You'll see that I'm using .then in the last line, because in the global scope you can't use await

You could, however do something like

```
(async () => {
  await resetSettings();
  moreFunctionsHere();
})();
```

an async IIFE so you can await

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I started to learn JS and programming this month, there are a LOT of things that I am still learning. I will take a look at  Promises and async/await. But I tried your code here, and it works. Thank you